# Problems getting a call stack in a release build

Tags: winapi, callstack

I have been struggling to get a call stack in a Windows executable. I have tried several different ways to obtain the call stack. The following are some examples. Note that I modified them slightly and removed error handling to make them easy to understand so they may not compile as is. I think you get the point.

The simple way:

```
const int max_entries = 10;
void *entries[max_entries];
return CaptureStackBackTrace(0, max_entries, entries, 0);
```

The low level way:

```
const int max_entries = 10;
void *entries[max_entries];

void **frame = 0;
__asm { mov frame, ebp }
unsigned int i = 0;
while(frame && i < max_entries) {
    entries[i++] = frame[1];
    frame = (void **)frame[0];
}
```

The compatible way:

```
void *entries[max_entries];
CONTEXT context;
RtlCaptureContext(&context);
STACKFRAME64 stack_frame;
ZeroMemory(&stack_frame, sizeof(STACKFRAME64));
stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset    = context.Eip;
stack_frame.AddrPC.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
stack_frame.AddrFrame.Offset = context.Ebp;
stack_frame.AddrFrame.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
stack_frame.AddrStack.Offset = context.Esp;
stack_frame.AddrStack.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;

unsigned int num_frames = 0;
while (true) {
    if (!StackWalk64(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386, GetCurrentProcess(),
        GetCurrentThread(), &stack_frame, &context, NULL,
        SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL))
        break;

    if (stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset == 0)
        break;

    entries[num_frames++] = reinterpret_cast<void *>(stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset);
}
```

My problem is that they work in an unoptimized build, but not with full optimization on. What happens is that I get one broken entry and then they exits their loops. In debug I get the full call stack and when I later look up the symbols, it is all correct.

I don't understand how it can be hard to make this work in all builds when the debugger does it all the time. I can specifically say that the frame pointers are not omitted in the code generation. I build for debug first and then only change the optimization from none to full optimization and rebuild to reproduce the call stack failure.

Any hints to a solution will be greatly appreciated.

/Jonas

Comment: You're not compiling with frame pointer optimization turned on, are you?

Comment: Frame pointers are not omitted in the code generation, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

I got this working using the "compatible way" now. I use the following code to initialize the context:

```
#define GET_CURRENT_CONTEXT(c, contextFlags) \
    do { \
        memset(&c, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT)); \
        c.ContextFlags = contextFlags; \
        __asm    call x \
        __asm x: pop eax \
        __asm    mov c.Eip, eax \
        __asm    mov c.Ebp, ebp \
        __asm    mov c.Esp, esp \
    } while(0);

CONTEXT context;
GET_CURRENT_CONTEXT(context, CONTEXT_FULL);
```

and then continue to fetch the stack using StackWalk64 as before.

```
void *entries[max_entries];
STACKFRAME64 stack_frame;
ZeroMemory(&stack_frame, sizeof(STACKFRAME64));
stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset    = context.Eip;
stack_frame.AddrPC.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
stack_frame.AddrFrame.Offset = context.Ebp;
stack_frame.AddrFrame.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
stack_frame.AddrStack.Offset = context.Esp;
stack_frame.AddrStack.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;

unsigned int num_frames = 0;
while (true) {
    if (!StackWalk64(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386, GetCurrentProcess(),
        GetCurrentThread(), &stack_frame, &context, NULL,
        SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL))
        break;

    if (stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset == 0)
        break;

    entries[num_frames++] = reinterpret_cast<void *>(stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset);
}
```

I noticed that I forgot to clear the CONTEXT structure before sending it to RtlCaptureContext so I tried to do it like this (because I would prefer to use the RtlCaptureContext function).

```
CONTEXT context;
memset(&context, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));
context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
RtlCaptureContext(&context);
```

Now RtlCaptureContext crashes, so I went back to using the GET_CURRENT_CONTEXT macro.

Comment: Hi Jonas, is it possible to map retrieved  entries[]  to the actual function names in optimized builds ? I get incorrect result. Do you have any example ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but just a "me too" report to clarify specific versions:

I'm seeing sporadic crashes inside `RtlCaptureContext` but only on 32-bit Debug builds and not on 32-bit Release builds, and not on either Debug or Release 64-bit builds.  I'm using VS2008 SP1 with `dbghelp.dll` fileVersion 6.12.2.633 from Debugging Tools for Windows downloaded April 25, 2011, and that dbghelp.dll copied into the same directory as my EXE prior to invocation.

This is with compiling using the exact same release of VS2008 SP1 compiler on the same Windows XP 64-bit SP2 machine (compiling both 32-bit and 64-bit native apps, no .NET managed code at all is in the mix).

The key above is it's *sporadic* nature. I have not determined the conditions by which it crashes.